# a function that return all possible sub arrays that sum up to a specific given number (need not to be a continuous sub array)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm stuck with this problem when I was doing some math and I need to find all possible sums of a given number. Here is a sample input and output for a better understanding of the problem.
Let say we are given an array `arr=[1,2,3,4,5]` and given number `number=10` then i need something like this,

```
def solution(arr,number):
    #you can code here
```

output : `[1,2,3,4],[2,3,5],[1,5,4],[1,3,6],[1,6]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: 1) Number 6 is not in arr, so why is there `[1, 3, 6] and [1, 6]`?  And 2) `[1, 6]` sums to 7 not 10, so another reason not to include it.

Comment: Yeah, I mistakenly forgot to add 6 in the last of the array and there had to four written instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are many interesting answers and discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392143/python-implementations-of-packing-algorithm) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements).

Here is a quick (tested) answer for you:

```py
import itertools

def solution(arr, number):
    for i in range(len(arr)+1):
        for s in list(itertools.combinations(arr, i)):
            if sum(s) == number:
                yield list(s)


arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
number = 10

print(list(solution(arr, number)))
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Well that is fine but this does not give all the arrays. [1,3,6] and [4,6] is not printed.

Comment: You just need to add the 6 to the array.   It was not included in your original question so I left it out.  Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Solve using Dynamic Programming algorithm

```
def solve(arr, s, i = None, path = None, solutions = None):
  """Use Dynamic Programming to find subsequence of arr
     that sum to s
     
     Arguments:
         arr      - array
         i        - current index that will use or not for arr
         path     - current subsequence we are summing
        solutions - all solutions found
  """
  # Set defaults
  if i is None:
    i = len(arr) - 1
  if solutions is None:
    solutions = []
  if path is None:
    path = []

  # Base Cases
  if s == 0:
    solutions.append(path[:])
    return solutions

  if i < 0 or s < 0:
    return

  # Try with arr[i] in path
  if arr[i] <= s:
    solve(arr, s-arr[i], i-1, [arr[i]] + path, solutions)

  # Try with arr[i] not in path
  solve(arr, s, i-1, path, solutions)

  return solutions
```

**Test**

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(solve(arr, 10))
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```